# git push: everything up-to-date / git status has changes committed:

Tags: git

Yesterday, git was working normally.  I was making changes and uploading changes to origin/master.

```
git commit -a -m 'comment'
git push
```

Today, when I did the sequence, after making modifications the git push did not recognize the commits.   Can someone help explain what is going on... and how to fix it.    I have provided a copy of the git log
(I do know how to do a git clone and migrate the changes into a new clone, but I am trying to understand why git commits are not working?)

Sequence below

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   requirements.txt
    new file:   src/bin/setup_linux.sh
    deleted:    src/echo
```

When I run git push I get everything up-to-date

```
git push
Username for 'http://gitURL': gitUID
Password for 'http://gitURL': 
Everything up-to-date



git log
```

commit df3a71f7af9070a826a3742751611d3d3fa898a9
Author: gitUID 
Date:   Mon Oct 12 16:54:51 2015 -0400

```
fix docs
```

commit a8c5867222147e366fc968e9b47daa5d237ecde5
Author: gitUID 
Date:   Mon Oct 12 16:53:28 2015 -0400

```
fix docs
```

Answer (score 0):

`git push` only cares about changes that have been committed. Your `git status` shows that you have outstanding changes, and also that there are no new commits since the last time you pushed/pulled. Conclusion: *you have not made any commits*, and so there is nothing to be pushed.

Comment: Thanks.  I firmly believed I had done a prior commit.  But you were right... I did the add, then commit and push worked.   Strange???

Looks like it is my mistake.

Comment: Well, I for one know I had been rich if I'd had a dollar for every time I was certain I had done something, then discovered I hadn't done it...

Answer (score 0):

Add/commit were not performed before push.   User error.